# Diagnosing the reason of Kernel Panic and forcible shutdowns on a Win 10 Laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, diagnostic, kernel-panic

I have a laptop purchased in 2014 with the following spec:

```
XMG U705 ULTIMATE Gaming Notebook
. NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980M 8192MB GDDR5 with G-Sync
. Intel Core i7-4790 | 4 Kerne | 8 Threads | 3,6 - 4,0GHz | TDP: 84 Watt
. 32GB (4x8192) SO-DIMM DDR3 RAM 2133MHz HyperX
```

I also got 2 X 256GB Samsung EVO SSDs to replace original HDDs, I've also installed Window 10 on it. I use laptop as a desktop replacement and for gaming (the likes of Borderlands 2 etc.)

The laptop worked quite well up until November 2018 when the problem started.

**The problem:** Shortly after powering on the laptops starts flashing led indicators and beeping loudly for 40-50 seconds and then it shuts down. Most times beeping starts before Win 10 loading but there are times when Windows gets loaded and then beeping starts, which still results in a shutdown. One time out of 10 the laptops gets loaded and keeps working for days, typically until Windows update kicks in and reboot happens. In those rare times when it boots and loads successfully sometimes I can still hear short beeping but then it changes its mind and keeps on till next reboot.

I did a bit of a research and found that a few other folks [encountered](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/xmg-u705-ec-firmware-panic-help.823386/) the same problem at around the time as myself. I've installed XMG's diagnostics tools to check the processor temperature and it was okay 55-70 degrees. I also disassembled the laptops and swapped CPU and GPU fans - which won me one successful startup (possibly coincidentally). the laptop looks healthy inside no signs of thermal or any other kind damage.

Could anyone suggest on how do I find the reason of these forcible shutdowns?